# UISearchBar in UINavigationBar can't add UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add a UISearchBar to a UINavigationbar using `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`

The UISearchBar gets added quite well into the UINavigationBar, but the left/right UIBarButtons are gone. I just can't figure out how to add them.

Andy ideas or examples on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb error from mine. When using `self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;` You need to use `self.searchDisplayController.navigationItem` to add the UIBarButtons. Now it is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

For others viewing this thread, elaborating Ben's answer is what worked for me.
`[self.searchDisplayController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem: self.sidebarButton];`